# CSV won't download properly

Tags: php

On my list.php page, I have written code to create a csv file.This file is saved to my plugin folder.

At the bottom of this page, I have included a link where, if the user wants to download this file, they can click on this link.

```
<a href="file.php">Download CSV</a>
```

On my file.php page I have included the following code:

```
   $sFile =  "myfile.csv";
   header('Content-Type: application/csv');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=<?php echo $sFile />;');
```

The save as pop up displays, but when I open the file, it is empty.
I have checked that the file does contain data and it does.

I can't figure out what I have done wrong.

Comment: `filename=' . $sFile`. Then you need to output the contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't work the way you expect. `<?php echo $sFile />` is a wrong part.
Just replace the quotes with double ones for string interpolation and use the variable directly (or just use concatenation). NOTE! This should not be used with user input without sanitization - if you would make the user choose the file name, don't forget about security.

```
$sFile =  "myfile.csv";
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$sFile;\"");
```